# Error sending mail via mu4e

Tags: debugging, mu4e

I get the following error after sending mail via `mu4e`:

```
Error (message-sent-hook): Error running hook #[0 "\301\302\303 !\207" [mu4e-sent-func mu4e-sent-handler mu4e~proc-sent buffer-file-name] 2] because: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (path maildir) Add the message at PATH to the database.
With MAILDIR set to the maildir this message resides in,
e.g. '/drafts'.

 if this works, we will receive (:info add :path <path> :docid
<docid> :fcc <path>). (mu4e~proc-send-command cmd:sent path:%s maildir:%s (mu4e~escape path) (mu4e~escape maildir))) 1)
```

Though the mail is sent, it seems that there is an issue with refiling because `mu4e~proc-send` is missing one argument.

Any way to get rid of this error?